# Counting instances in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this tag system for tagging blog entries and such. The tags are in one table, containing only a tag name and a primary key. Then I have another table with objects that are using the tags.

It could look something like this:

```
_________________________________
| tags                          |
--------------------------------|
| id  | name                    |
|-------------------------------|
|  1  | Scuba diving            |
|  2  | Dancing                 |
---------------------------------

_________________________________
| tag_objects                   |
--------------------------------|
| id  | tag  | object           |
|-------------------------------|
|  1  |  2   | 13               |
|  2  |  2   | 18               |
|  3  |  1   | 24               |
---------------------------------
```

Now, what I need to accomplish is to to add a column to the tags table, called "occurrences" or something. For each tag in tags, occurrences should be set to the number of times that tag is used in tag_objects.

So basically something like (obviously pseudo-code):

```
foreach(tags):
    UPDATE tags
       SET occurrences = (SELECT COUNT(id) 
                            FROM tag_objects 
                           WHERE tag = tags.id);
```

When people create new posts and stuff in the future, I'll just have a trigger to update the count, but I have a couple of thousand rows already that I need to count first. I don't know how to do this, so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, without any extra tables, would be:

First add the extra field:

> mysql> alter table tags add occurs int
>   default 0;

Then just update this new field with the number of occurences.

> mysql> update tags left join (select tag,
>   count(id) as cnt from tag_objects
>   group by tag) as subq on
>   tags.id=subq.tag set
>   occurs=coalesce(subq.cnt,0);

Note the use of the left join to ensure all tags are counted, even the unused ones. The coalesce-function will convert NULL to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have done a good work, your query must work.

But, this will result in awful performance. I advise you to recreate a table :

```
CREATE TABLE newTags AS
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM tags t
    INNER JOIN tag_objects to
        ON to.tag = tags.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

This will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need to denormalize your data, you should stay away from that.  Counting on indexed columns is usually very fast.  I am a big fan of clean and normalized data  ;-)

Comment: It hurts my soul as well, but this database is already on its knees, and it has been through far, far nastier things than this. We have a fair bit of traffic as well, so any way to reduce the work the database has to do on each page load is needed.

Comment: Ah!  I see...  ;-)  In a previous job I was in this situation.  We spent months on optimization and it worked, lets say, at 50%.  We really corrected the problem by chyanging hardware and by upgrading (that was an Oracle DB).  GL!

Answer (score 1):

I would generally not want to store computed values in columns on the database - it's messy, can easily get out of sync, and offends the deities of normalization.

However, if you really must have a database entity with the count, rather than calculating on the fly, I'd create a view (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) which stores the pre-computed value, using the SQL provided by Scorpio

```
CREATE view tag_occurences AS
SELECT t.id, t.name, 
COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM tags t
    INNER JOIN tag_objects to
        ON to.tag = tags.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

Comment: MySQL does not support materialized views, so this would not store anything.  It would run the query every time.

Comment: It doesn't need to be materialized - it's just stuffing the query into a view, rather than running it every time. But, like you, I would just run the query, rather than go through the view....

Comment: You misunderstand.  In MySQL, querying through a view is exactly the same as running the query directly.  It does not precompute any values.  Using a view saves nothing with respect to optimization, execution, or table I/O.

Comment: Yeah, I know that - but I don't think performance was top of the priorities in the question. In fact, he doesn't mention performance as a concern at all. I'd argue that this may perform better than writing the value to persistent storage - the trigger (if he uses the SQL from the accepted answer) will be very slow as the data grows, because it doesn't limit the update to the current record. If the tables are nicely indexed, and don't have ridiculous numbers of records, the plain "run the query every time someone hits the view" strategy should work okay...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will gain better performance if you will be incrementing and decrementing the value of `occurrences` on table `tag_objects` insert/delete trigger.

Comment: Definitely, and I will do that in the future. However, I'm implementing this on top of a fairly old database that already has a few thousand rows. I only intend to run this once, and then add a trigger to update it.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It all depends on the number of updates/inserts/deletes! If that number is large the trigger may actually lock the tags table for so long that thing slow down by a lot!

Comment: In standard case tag data is read more than changed. If not the tag usage is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Your psuedeo code will work exactly as written (without the foreach loop). At least it would in oracle, I assume MySQL lets you use a correlated subquery as the value too.

Answer (score 0):

For the inserting of new rows you could use a query like:
`INSERT INTO tags VALUES(x,y,z,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE occurrences = occurrences+1;`
I didn't check the syntax, but something like that.